# How to repeat platform and background overlap2d and libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, overlap2d

I am creating game with Libgdx and Overlap2d.

I don't know how to repeat platform. It's like I already added some platform to the screen but it only show one time. I want to show it randomly at random speed also repeat and change background.

Comment: Please be more specific and show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Following methods worked for me, hope they do for you too.

Platform creation

Create a array list with platform class, measure the distance of the object traveled and make some conditions inside the loop. Retrieve the platform class from array list assign the position and length (using a 'while loop' may be).

For Random velocity, I have used following code.

```
platform.velocity( MathUtils.random(10,20),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have dynamic scene generation, you have to use factory methods to create them on the fly. 
First get the factory, it makes things for you. You get it from sceneLoader.getEntityFactory()
If platform is just a nine patch, then create a 9patch VO object and feed it to factory's createEntity method, if it's more complex object, that you can create it in editor, and convert to composite, then add composite to library, and then from sceneLoader get the VO of that library item by name, and feed that VO to the factory. Either way you get a ready to go entity, which you can add to the engine, make sure to pass sceneLoader.getRoot as the root entity, when creating the entity, so that it has the correct parent.

Other way is you can re-use platforms that you create with the editor. in that case you just have to put many on the scene, and the position them somehow using TransformComponent from your code.

Hope this helps.